# Exp:resso Store issue with index.php

Tags: expresso-store, ee2

So I have this website I put together. Everything works fine, except 1 tiny weird issue.

Whenever the URL does **NOT** have /index.php/ in it. All the Store buttons just refresh the page and do not work properly. Add to cart fails, checkout fails, any Store generated button just plain fails and only refreshes the page.

Does anyone know of this issue? Or how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, i figured it out. This website was upgraded from a ZENcart installation. I never updated the .htaccess file. I just replaced it with ...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and it seems to have solved the issue.